# Не вызывается обработчик события в Yii2, как дебажить?

Tags: yii2, события, behaviors

Здравствуйте. Создал поведение, добавил 4 события. Три события от `yii\db\ActiveRecord` отрабатывают как положено (при работе с моделью), а четвертое от `yii\web\View` не происходит, когда рендерится страница.

Поведение подключил в контроллере.

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['POST'],
            ],
        ],
        'SeoBehavior' => [
            'class' => SeoBehavior::class,
        ]
    ];
}
```

В поведении обработчик не срабатывает.

```
class SeoBehavior extends Behavior
{

public function events()
{
    return [
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'beforeInsert',
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'beforeUpdate',
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_VALIDATE => 'beforeValidate',
        View::EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE => 'beginPage',
//      View::EVENT_BEGIN_PAGE => function(){var_dump([1]);exit;},
    ];
}
```

Пробовал анонимкой, тоже не срабатывает. Такое ощущение, что указанное событие наступает позже (оно ведь должно наступать когда-то?).

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается для того, что бы срабатывало событие `beginPage`, необходимо в конфиге в секции `components` явно это указать.

```
    'view' => [
        'as seo' => [
            'class' => SeoBehavior::class,
        ],
    ],
```